# Can I create keytab for authentication of user in unix server

Tags: linux, active-directory, authentication, kerberos

I have a service which needs to authenticate against another service using Kerberos. Normal credentials expire rather quickly - can I create a keytab or something for the service to get the ticket without password?

I don't have admin for Kerberos server but I do have local admin for AD member.

Comment: sure, here you see an example how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454308/script-kerberos-ktutil-to-make-keytabs

Comment: @natxoasenjo Thanks. Is there a way to restrict it to one service only?

Comment: @natxoasenjo Google? But most examples are about adding principal (user@domain) without restricting it to a service - I'd like ideally to allow user@domain to authenticate using keytab to SERVICE/host@domain. Currently I'm not sure if that's even possible as I cannot find place to put SERVICE/host@domain (if it isn't - oh well...)

Comment: that's not trying ;-). If you want to restrict it to a spn, then you need to add a spn attribute to the ldap object (user/computer).

Comment: @natxoasenjo so in short I cannot as I don't have admin right to AD/LDAP/Kerberos. Somehow I don't think trying to pas `--spn` parameter to `add_entry` would help move me forward with this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, but you're going to need to involve your AD Admin and they are going to have to set an SPN on the user object your keytab refers to.

I know this because we've used a few of these in one of my production environments. Hope it helps you out.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241(v=ws.11).aspx